# What would I need to run in order to install task "fix scss"?

Tags: deployment, sass, gruntjs

I am working on a team task. When instructed by a piece of documentation to run `grunt fix scss` I did so, and I received the following message:

> jit-grunt: Plugin for the "fix" task not found. If you have installed
>   the plugin already, please setting the static mapping. See
>   https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt#static-mappings
>
> Warning: Task "fix" failed. Use --force to continue.

The problem is that I have no idea whether the plugin they mention is installed. What command would I need to run in order to install this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was running `grunt fix scss` rather than `grunt fix-scss` (with a hyphen).

Once I did the latter, I got more meaningful output.